# How to calculate the float number value to store in memory using IEEE 754, 32 bit float?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I got the following question:

***You want to calculate the float number value to store in memory using IEEE 754, 32 bit float. Which one of the exactly value will you be got from 101111100010000000000000000000001 ?***

And the answer is: `-0.15625`

Can anyone show me how to do that?

Comment: With a 2 in it?  "But there's no such thing as 2!"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial which explains how IEEE floats are encoded. http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm